# Common divisor of Gaussian coefficient expressions

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory, algebraic-combinatorics, q-analogs, finite-geometry

I have a question about common divisors of some expressions involving Gaussian coefficients, in particular in the case ${n \brack 1}_{q} = \frac{q^{n}-1}{q-1}$ where $q$ is a prime power.

It is well known that the greatest common divisor
$$\gcd{\left( {a \brack 1}_{q}, {b \brack 1}_{q}\right)} = {d \brack 1}_{q}$$
where $d = \gcd{(a,b)}$.

If we assume that $a,b \geq 1$, $a+b < n$, is there an easy way to determine the following?
$$\gcd{\left({n \brack 1}_{q},\ q^{a}{b \brack 1}_{q} \pm 1\right)}$$

This has come up in some research I am doing. In particular I am hoping to find a nice way to determine when this $\gcd$ is 1.

I do know that if $n = a+kb+s$ for some $0 \leq s < b$ then
$${n \brack 1}_{q} = q^{a}{b \brack 1}_{q}q^{s}\frac{q^{kb}-1}{q^{b}-1} + {s \brack 1}_{q}$$
which I'm hoping can help.

Comment: In the ring $\Bbb Q[q]$?

Comment: @runway44 I was thinking of $q$ being a fixed (prime power) integer, and just looking at divisibility in $\mathbb{Z}$. But certainly thinking of $q$ as an indeterminate, and looking at factoring in $\mathbb{Q}[q]$ is close to equivalent.

Comment: @runway44 Your deleted answer seems useful, with the modification that I think we need to consider that  $\zeta$ could be a $d$th root of unity for some $d \mid n$.

Comment: That's not a modification - if $d\mid n$ then any $d$th root of unity is an $n$th root of unity. I assume you're thinking of primitive roots of unity.

Comment: @runway44 I'm not saying that in this case $\zeta$ wouldn't also be an $n$th root of unity, but I'm thinking of your conclusion at the end, that if $\zeta^{b} = \zeta^{-1}$ then $b = n-1$; if $\zeta$ is also a $d$th root of unity for some $d < n$, there are other possibilities for $b$.